# How to pass a reference of a class to a function inside of a different class in C#/XNA/monogame?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

So, I have an enemy and when it dies it needs to be deleted. So, in the base class for that class I'm trying to put in a function which deletes the first class however I'm having trouble passing in a reference to the class. How can I pass the reference or is there another way to delete the class that is better?

Just ask if you need clarification as I am having trouble explaining this.

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        alive = false;
        //This is not working \/
        killswitch(ref Game1.ant1);
        //Kills bug and gives out loot etc.
    }
    else if (position == house1 || position == house2 || position == house3 || position == house4
        || position == house5 || position == house6 || position == house7 || position == house8
        || position == house9 || position == house10 || position == house11 || position == house12)
    {
        killswitch(ref Game1.ant1);
    }

    public void killswitch(ref Ant ant1)
    {
        //This is where loot is given
        Global.money += bountyGiven;
        //delete class code here

    }
```

Comment: Show some code. You've done exactly the same as your last question... we can only guess what you're trying to do. Show us what you're doing instead.

Comment: Not exactly but I'll put in some code

Comment: See so I need to pass in a reference to ant1 (which is made in Game1.cs) so I can delete the class.

Comment: What is `Game1.ant1`? `killswitch` accepts no parameters, why are you trying to pass one?

Comment: You're right. I've updated the code but it still says: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: I dunno if this helps but its a link to the error help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CS0120);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true

Comment: I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Game1 probably shouldn't be static and I would expect it to have a collection of ants and then have a method like KillAnt or RemoveAnt.

Comment: @Detinator10: again, show the definition of `Game.ant1`.

Comment: @Detinator10 "In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must first create an object instance." from the link you posted. So either make ant1 static (probably a horrible idea), or make it visible in your Update method. I actually find it strange that `this.ant1` or simply `ant1` doesn't work but I don't remember how XNA looked like all that well.

Comment: Game1 is not static, ant1 is the actual instance of the enemy, and yeah I was expecting just ant1 to work.

Comment: And if i put a function in Game1 to kill an ant (I only have one right now (but will have more later)) how will it know which ant I'm referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing from head... this could give you a hint how to handle unlimited number of ants.

```
Public Class Ant
   public position as vector2
   public health as integer = 100
   public isdead ad boolean = false
End class

Public Class Ants
   Inherit list (of Ant)

   Public Sub AddAnt(Position)
   // add new ant to list
   End Sub

   Public Sub Update()
    For Each ant As ant In ants
      If Not(ant.isdead)
        // update ants
      End If
    Next

    Me.RemoveAll(function(c) c.isdead = true)

   End Sub

   Public Sub Draw()
     For Each ant As ant In ants
      If not(ant.isdead)
        // draw ants
      End If        
     Next
   End Sub

End class
```

Comment: What's a sub (I'm a new programmer)

Comment: sorry i didnt see you asked for c#... i wrote in (pseudo) basic. sub is void in c#

Comment: Would you mind translating it to C# I've never worked with basic before

Comment: Thank you this has worked perfectly so far. The one thing I haven't translated is 'Me.Removeall(...)' but I will read up on it. Anyway thank you so much!!!

Comment: check here for `Me.RemoveAll()`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2